# How to restart Azure Web App farm instance VM

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, kudu

Is there any way of simply rebooting the VM in which a site resides?

Had an issue today where git deploying a code change to our site resulted in:

```
D:\home\site\repository\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(67,5): error MSB6006: "csc.exe" exited with code -1073741819. [D:\home\site\repository\Foo\Bar.csproj]
```

Eventually after killing VBCSCompiler.exe in the Kudu/SCM site Process Explorer and issuing a Redeploy from the portal, resulted in a successful deployment ... but then the site wouldn't spin up correctly: in EventLog.xml there was

```
HttpCompileException: External component has thrown an exception.
   at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
   at System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax()
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
```

So something pretty fundamental wasn't well with the environment.

The only thing that fixed it was choosing a different *App Service plan/pricing tier* in the portal which then seems to result in the sites spinning up in a new VM (we noticed that `%COMPUTERNAME%` changed).

Is there a better way to get a new VM instance than randomly swapping between different pricing tier every time this happens?

Answer (score 3):

You can try restarting the site right from the Azure Portal on the Web App management blade.

[image]

Comment: Also try Stop then Start which actually restarts w3wp. I think the restart does an app pool recycle instead or something different.

Comment: I think I tried the Restart. The Stop+Start on a test site does seems to result in a "fuller" restart, seeing as the site is then unavailable for over a minute and w3wp.exe does end up with a new PID. Might try that next time.

Comment: I think you have this backwards. Restart causes a deeper restart than stop/start, including cleaning up all the temp files. Also, stop/start does not affect the scm site, so it won't help with anything related to Kudu.

Comment: Ah thanks David, I was being a bit hasty perhaps as there appears to be a delay between issuing the Restart from the portal and the site recycling. I'll try this if it happens again - hopefully it'll help if we get these issues again in future.

Answer (score 3):

You already have all the answers, but to summarize:

You can't directly restart the VM a site runs on. But you can do two things instead:

1. Scale up and scale down your site. This will cause your site to be moved to a random VM
2. Stop and start your site. This will restart the w3wp process rather than restarting the VM.  Any other sites running on that same VM will not be affected.